# iTunes connect does not allow to enter multiline description

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I've just submitted my first app to the App Store and I have problem with description field in iTunes Connect - it does not allow me to enter multiline value. 
I've tried everything - copying-pasting from different editors, entering manually, etc.

If there is one line, like "Hello world" - it saves successfully.
When I've got at least 2 lines of text, lke

"Hello
World"

it just shows me the following error message and does not save:

> Description cannot contain control characters (for example, null, new lines, carriage returns, escape, and other invisible characters).

Comment: The error message specifically says "new lines" are not allowed. Why are you acting surprised when you get this error in response to putting newlines in your description?

Comment: This is not a programming question, but a support issue for Apple's iTunes Connect, so it is offtopic for this site.

Comment: Kevin, I'm surpised because:
1. According to the iTunes Connect Developer Guide it should allow "line breaks"
2. All apps in the app store have multiline descriptions...


Brad, yes, sorry, but faq says that it is allowed to ask quesions about commonly used developer tools. I believe iTunes connect can be considered as one of such tools :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry, this just started this morning, and is a bug that Apple has acknowledged.  Hopefully this will be fixed soon.  There are a lot of very unhappy people, me included, who can't get out important updates.

Comment: Looks like they have already fixed it! I've just tried once again and it's working. Anyway thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Unbelievably this bug is back!

You can use Google Chrome, it's just broken in Safari.

Comment: Broken in Chrome for me

Comment: Broken in all browsers for me

Comment: Boken on both browser Chome and Safari, I submitted a build a day before all went, now its not allowing me submit an update

Comment: Broken in all browsers.  Plus safari won't let me scroll down in iTunes connect.  Ugh

Comment: It was working as of roughly 4 p.m. Central this afternoon. Broken in all browsers now. Git revert!

Comment: Just broke. Broken in all browsers for me. Reproducible also in fastlane (via transporter) which is how I found it.

Comment: Disallowing multilines in Firefox and Safari today.

Comment: Broken in all browsers, not even allowing me to add a new line. Frustrating 

Comment: This really frustrated me last night, but this morning it's working again. Looks like another huge glitch that Apple quietly fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as an answer since I can't yet comment.

Not being able to enter multiline descriptions is an existing bug that only seems to occur sporadically. It is currently broken as of 8 hours ago on Chrome 51.0.2704.103 **and** Safari 9.1.1.

You can work around it by removing newlines, or waiting until Apple fixes the issue.

I'll report back when I see it fixed (I'm expecting the fix to take a day or two).

*Edit:* As of this morning, submitting to the App Store on Chrome with multiline descriptions is working!