# Description must not contain special characters (Itunes Connect)

Tags: app-store-connect

I was able to submit my app to ITunes connect for review with a good description. When I took off the app so I could make changes, I tried to resubmit it hours later, with the same exact description, and now it says:

> Description must not contain special characters (for example, null, new lines, carriage return, escape, and other invisible characters)

Is this a new rule for new apps just recently today?

Also, there is an error sign next to the Language setting, which I set to English.

---------UPDATE------

IT WORKS NOW! Finally. That was such a strange bug, especially since it was the first I ever encountered on Itunes connect.

Comment: Discussion on Apple Developer Forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/49915

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a bug of iTunes Connect.
Apparently it already happened once in [2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047990/itunes-connect-does-not-allow-to-enter-multiline-description).

UPDATE: it was a bug, and it is fixed now.

Comment: I have submitted a bug report to apple, I will post the results here.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with all my accounts and only one reult:

> Description must not contain special characters (for example, null, new lines, carriage return, escape, and other invisible characters)

This seems like a bug of iTunes Connect.  Hope it will be gone soon..

Answer (score 0):

Apple just fixed it.
I submitted my app done.
Get back to work, bros.